# how to get name of data.frame from list passed to function using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, evaluation

I have function which I want to extend with ability to save results to csv file. The name of csv file should be generated based on data.frame name passed to this function:

```
my.func1 <- function(dframe, ...){
  # PART OF CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR COMPUTATION
  # ...

  # PART OF CODE WHERE I WANT TO STORE RESULTS AS CSV
  csv <- deparse(substitute(dframe))
  csv
}
```

When I call this function following way then the name of dataset passed to this function is interpreted correctly:

```
> my.func1(mtcars)
[1] "mtcars"
```

But I need to call this function for each data.frame from list. If I call this function for particular data.frame from list then it is basically working (I get the ugly name containing also name of list but one workaround could be trim it using regular expression):

```
> LoDFs <- list(first=data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), y2=c(4,5,6)), second=data.frame(yA=c(1,2,3), yB=c(4,5,6)))
> my.func1(LoDFs$first)
[1] "LoDFs$first"
```

Problem is when I want to call this function for all data.frames from list. In this case the names of data.frame are mess:

```
> lapply(LoDFs, my.func1)
$first
[1] "X[[i]]"

$second
[1] "X[[i]]"

> lapply(seq_along(LoDFs), function(x) { my.func1(LoDFs[[x]]) })
[[1]]
[1] "LoDFs[[x]]"

[[2]]
[1] "LoDFs[[x]]"
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I avoid mentioned workaround with regular expressions and make code more robust?

Comment: Last time I was faced with a similar problem, I gave up and made a vector of the names of the data.frames, and then used get() to grab the data.frame. For you something like
lapply(names(LoDFs), my.func1), where the first line of my.funct1 is df <- Lodf[[n]]
I hope someone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

f each data frame in the list is named

```
lapply (names (LoDf),function(i)write.csv (my.fun1 (LoDf [[i]]),paste0 (i,'.csv')))
```

On phone so forgive small mistakes

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that lapply does not feed the name of the item in the list, it only feed the item itself.

An alternative solution is to use `mapply` which IMO is more specific about the input rather than relying on scoping

```
mapply(function(L,N){write.csv(L, paste0(N,".csv"));}, L=LoDFs,N=names(LoDFs))
```

Comment: @CarlBoneri may I ask how `mapply` can be replaced by `sapply`?

Comment: Quick example not related to this question  

`smp_li <- as.list(mtcars)  

`with_map <- mapply(sum,smp_li)  

`with_sap <- sapply(smp_li,sum)  

`> identical(with_map,with_sap)  
`[1] TRUE