# get the name of variable in function regardless of if it was passed directly or via *apply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, evaluation

I can get the content and name of passed data.frame to function following way:

```
my.func1 <- function(dframe, ...){
  content <- dframe
  name    <- deparse(substitute(dframe))
  name
}

> my.func1(mtcars)
[1] "mtcars"
```

I have list of data.frames and I need to call this function for each data.frame from this list. There are several possible ways to do it, mentioned in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320460/how-to-get-name-of-data-frame-from-list-passed-to-function-using-lapply), e.g.:

```
> LoDFs <- list(first=data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), y2=c(4,5,6)), second=data.frame(yA=c(1,2,3), yB=c(4,5,6)))
> lapply(names(LoDFs), function(x) { x })
[[1]]
[1] "first"

[[2]]
[1] "second"
```

This one is working because I'm passing the names to function directly and when I want access the content of data.frame inside function I can use `LoDFs[[x]]`. Can I write one type of function which will be able to get the name of data.frame regardless of if was passed directly (1st example) or using `lapply` from list (2nd example)?

PS: I was thinking if it would be possible to somehow determine the "parent" function and if this parent would be `*apply` then I will handle it differently but I do not know if this is correct approach.

**EDIT In reply to G. Grothendieck**

Ok, so I've rewritten `my.func1` to

```
my.func1 <- function(dframe.val, dframe.name, ...){
  value <- dframe.val
  name  <- dframe.name
  name
}
```

Example of calling it for each data.frame from list using `mapply`:

```
mapply(my.func1, LoDFs, names(LoDFs))
```

Example of calling it directly:

```
my.func1(mtcars, as.character(substitute(mtcars)))
```

It is one more parameter but seems that it is working (I'm not 100% sure if `as.character(substitute(mtcars))` is correct way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If LoDFs is used in a `lapply` the names are lost but `mapply` can be used to pass both the names and values:

```
fun <- function(nm, DF) sprintf("%s has %d rows", nm, nrow(DF))
mapply(fun, names(LoDFs), LoDFs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done:

```
fun <- function(df,...) {
    call1 <- sys.call(1L);
    if (grepl(perl=T,'apply$',as.character(call1[[1L]]))) {
        name <- df;
        df <- get(envir=sys.frame(-2L),as.character(call1[[2L]][[2L]]))[[name]];
    } else {
        name <- substitute(df);
        if (length(name)==3L && as.character(name[[1L]])=='$') {
            name <- as.character(name[[3L]]);
        } else {
            name <- deparse(name);
        }; ## end if
    }; ## end if
    print(name);
    print(df);
    invisible();
}; ## end fun()
```

Direct argument:

```
fun(mtcars);
## [1] "mtcars"
##                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
## Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
## Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
## Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
## Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
## Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
## Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
## Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
## Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
## Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
## Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
## Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
## Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
## Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
## Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
## Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
## Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
## AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
## Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
## Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
## Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
## Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
## Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
## Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
## Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
## Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
## Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Named list dereference:

```
fun(LoDFs$first);
## [1] "first"
##   y1 y2
## 1  1  4
## 2  2  5
## 3  3  6
fun(LoDFs$second);
## [1] "second"
##   yA yB
## 1  1  4
## 2  2  5
## 3  3  6
```

Named list apply:

```
invisible(lapply(names(LoDFs),fun));
## [1] "first"
##   y1 y2
## 1  1  4
## 2  2  5
## 3  3  6
## [1] "second"
##   yA yB
## 1  1  4
## 2  2  5
## 3  3  6
```

Comment: thank you very much, this shows for me very interesting language internals which I plan to study soon.